# how can we write binary file to a VHD file on mac

Tags: virtual-machine, nasm

I wanted to write  x86 Assembly code .then Compile to binary file . the program only print a string o the screen.

```
move ax,0xb800
move ds,ax
move [0x00],word'a'
move [0x02],word's'
move [0x04],word'm'
jmp $
```

now i have the binary file . but i dont know how to write it into vhd file.（I want to put the code at The first 512 bytes so the code will work after bios starting）

can i just open the hvd file and the binary file then copy byte by byte？

I hope I can get some ideas . If you have the code would be better

Answer (score 0):

On linux, you may create the vhd file via virtualbox first, and execute the command following to copy the content of the mbr sector into the vhd file.
`dd if=c05_mbr.bin of=LEARN-ASM.vhd bs=512 count=1 conv=notrunc`
With the option 'notrunc', the size of the output file will not change when it is bigger than the input file's.